# In building Spark, the jars built from sbt and maven are different

Tags: maven, apache-spark, sbt

I want to build Spark 3.0.0 Streaming submodule source code by myself and install them into the local repository, then reuse it, but I faced a wired problem. If I build Streaming in Maven, everything is ok. But if I build it by Sbt, the jar will lack dependency.

The reason for not using Maven is because it takes too long to package, it's not suitable for iterative development.

**Maven**

command: `mvn install -DskipTests -pl streaming`

When I use the jar built by myself, everything is ok.

**Sbt**

command: `sbt`, `project streaming`, `publishLocal`.

When I use it, the system cannot work because of the lack of dependency. The error message is as follows:

```java
20/09/07 00:12:16 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Called receiver 0 onStart
20/09/07 00:12:16 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Receiver started again
20/09/07 00:12:17 INFO SocketReceiver: Closed socket to localhost:9000
Exception in thread "Socket Receiver" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter.acquire()V
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.RateLimiter.waitToPush(RateLimiter.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.BlockGenerator.addData(BlockGenerator.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl.pushSingle(ReceiverSupervisorImpl.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver.store(Receiver.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.SocketReceiver.receive(SocketInputDStream.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.SocketReceiver$$anon$1.run(SocketInputDStream.scala:72)
20/09/07 00:12:20 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1599408740000 ms
20/09/07 00:12:20 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1599408740000 ms.0 from job set of time 1599408740000 ms
```

I don't know where the problem occurred when package in Sbt.

Comment: That `NoSuchMethodError` seems to be due to dependency version mismatch not "lack of dependency". Can you `package` (not `publishLocal` as it goes to ~/.ivy2 not ~/.m2, but it doesn't really matter here).